# What should I do to fix 'reply from x.x.x.x, destination host unreachable' when trying to ping to a linux server?

Tags: ping

I am trying to ping a remote linux server from Windows 8.1 computer. Every time I ping to the server, I get 'Reply from x.x.x.x : Destination Host Unreachable'. I checked that pinging to other IP address works, but the certain IP address of the remote linux server doesn't work expectedly. What should I do to fix it?
I've done dns flush, arp -d, and else...

Comment: Nothing. You may have routing issues, firewall activated on linux, etc.

Comment: Do you know which device has IP address x.x.x.x? You could try reaching the server from other machines. You could put "destination host unreachable" (with the quotes) in a search engine. As far as causes of your problem are concerned: The server could be down. There may be no route to this address. The server may be configured to ignore ICMP echo requests (also known as "pings"). A firewall around the server might block echo requests. By the way, this has nothing to do with UNIX or Linux.

Comment: Thank you Romeo and berndbausch! Actually I found out that the server was crushed and needed reinstallation of os.....It is solved now. Thank you for comments.

Comment: Please consider deleting your question since you found the problem and it is not relevant unix.stackexhange.com. Thank you.